# Explicit return type based on Array.isArray()

Tags: typescript

I have a function which can return a type `O` or alternatively `O[]`:

```
public convert(data?: I | I[]) {
  if (data) {
    this.input(data);
  }

  if (!this._data) {
    const e = new Error("You must first set the data before trying to convert!");
    e.name = "NotReady";
    throw e;
  }

  return Array.isArray(this._data)
    ? this._convertArray(this._data) as O
    : this._convertObject(this._data) as O[];
}
```

The return type is determined by what the user inputs as data:

```
public input(data: I | I[]) {
  this._data = data;
  return this;
}
```

In summary:

- if user sends in input typed as `I`; `convert()` will return output of type `O`
- if user sends in input typed as `I[]`; `convert()` will return output of type `O[]`

I initially thought the conditional statement in the return of `convert` would be enough but that didn't work. I'm guessing I'm not being creative enough but I'm running into a wall. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so if user enters array `I[]` you should return array `I[]`, if enters `I` you should return `I` ?

Comment: yes that is correct; explicitly, if they input an array (aka, I[]) then an output array (O[]) is returned. If they put in an input Object (aka, I) then an output object is return (aka, O)

Comment: so what's the problem if you will return just `this._data` ?

Comment: this._data is the “unconverted” type; what is returned is a converted type (aka, type I => type O ... or type I[] => type O[])

Comment: I now see that my description of the question is a bit off; i will correct ... fixed

Comment: @ken no automatic way to do it. You will need to use multiple overloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is no way to avoid ambiguity in the return type for `convert` so to make client calls easier I have extended the public API in the following way:

```
public convertArray(data?: I[]) {
  if(!data && !Array.isArray(this._data)) {
    const e = new Error(`Using convertArray() requires that the input is also an array and it is of type ${typeof this._data}`);
    e.name = "TypedMapper::InvalidFormat";
    throw e;
  }
  return this.convert(data) as O[];
}

public convertObject(data?: I) {
  if(!data && Array.isArray(this._data)) {
    const e = new Error(`Using convertObject() requires that the input is an object and it is of type ${typeof this._data}`);
    e.name = "TypedMapper::InvalidFormat";
    throw e;
  }
  return this.convert(data) as O;
}
```

A client can still use `convert()` but will need to typecast to use effectively. Instead a more convenient syntax would be:

```
 const result = tm.convertObject(objInput); // typed to O
 const result2 = tm.convertArray(arrInput); // typed to O[]
```

Answer (score 0):

In reference to your comment: *"the return of convert would be enough but that didn't work."* Are you seeing linting errors or are you getting errors during run time?

I've laid out some example code below that returns the correct content/type and does what I think you require. I have made at least two type-hinting additions - maybe this is what your code needed?

```
interface I {
  id: number;
}

interface O {
  guid: number;
}

class StackOverFlowQuestionClass {
  _data: I | I[];

  public convert(data?: I): O;
  public convert(data?: I[]): O[];

  public convert(data?: I | I[]): O | O[] {
    if (data) {
      this.input(data);
    }

    if (!this._data) {
      const e = new Error(
        "You must first set the data before trying to convert!"
      );
      e.name = "NotReady";
      throw e;
    }

    return Array.isArray(this._data)
      ? (this._convertArray(this._data as I[]) as O[])
      : (this._convertObject(this._data as I) as O);
  }

  public input(data: I | I[]) {
    this._data = data;
    return this;
  }

  public _convertArray(items: I[]): O[] {
    return items.map(item => this._convertObject(item));
  }

  public _convertObject(item: I): O {
    return { guid: item.id };
  }
}
```

Comment: run time works fine but at design time the return type for `convert()` is not known. Sounds like there's no way around this and so I have extended the API surface in a way similar to what you're showing here; though I am not exposing `_convertArray` as public as that doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: I've noticed you've posted your own answer and seem to be done with the question - I have however updated my answer, adding two method overloads. Intellisense seems to infer the type correctly during `design` time - for what it's worth.

Comment: I'll have a look later today; thanks for looking into this

Comment: the only differences I see in your code is more explicit typing in the return of `convert`; i did try that and it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types%20since%20TypeScript%202.8) since TypeScript 2.8

```
class Test<I, O> {
  private _data!: I | I[];

  convert<T extends I | I[]>(data?: T): T extends I[] ? O[] : O {
    if (data) {
      this.input(data);
    }

    if (!this._data) {
      const e = new Error('You must first set the data before trying to convert!');
      e.name = 'NotReady';
      throw e;
    }

    // note the `as any` you can use a // @ts-ignore comment if you prefer
    // @ts-ignore
    return Array.isArray(this._data) ? (this._convertArray(this._data as I[]) as any) : (this._convertObject(this._data as I) as any);
  }

  private input(data: I | I[]): void {
    // ...
  }
  private _convertArray(data: I[]): O[] {
    // ...
  }
  private _convertObject(data: I): O {
    // ...
  }
}

const a: Test<string, number> = new Test();

const b = a.convert(''); // number
const c = a.convert(['']); // number[]
```